# Phonegap / Cordova Video Player for all video files on mobile

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, android-video-player

I am new to mobile application development, I am trying to make video player using cordova/phonegap with the  help of html5. After searching a lot, I realized that playing a video without native android is not possible. Please help me in this regard, I want my app to fetch all video files from mobile storage and sdcard and list all of them. On clicking a customized video player starts playing that.
I tried this plugin first
https://github.com/amuelli/Html5Video
But no success.
Then, I tried other video plugins available but again no success. A code here I am pasting which gives an ugly output, but that's what I have reached yet, this code is without any plugin.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<style>
    div#video_player_box{ width:550px; background:#000; margin:0px auto;}
    div#video_controls_bar{ background: #333; padding:10px; color:#CCC;
    font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
        button#playpausebtn{
            background:url(pause.png);
            border:none;
            width:16px;
            height:18px;
            cursor:pointer;
            opacity:0.5;
        }
        button#playpausebtn:hover{ opacity:1; }
        input#seekslider{ width:180px; }
        input#volumeslider{ width: 80px;}
        input[type='range'] {
            -webkit-appearance: none !important;
            background: #000;
            border:#666 1px solid;
            height:4px;
        }
        input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-thumb {
            -webkit-appearance: none !important;
            background: #FFF;
            height:15px;
            width:15px;
            border-radius:100%;
            cursor:pointer;
        }
</style>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
    <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and   
      height=device-height attributes. See 
    https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, 
    maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-
    height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
    <title>Hello World</title>
    <script>
    var vid, playbtn, seekslider, curtimetext, durtimetext, mutebtn, 
    volumeslider, fullscreenbtn;
    $(document).on('ready',function(){
    var video = $("#video");

    function handleFileSelect(evt) {
        var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

        // Loop through the FileList and render image files as thumbnails.
        for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {

          // Only process image files.
          if (!f.type.match('video.*')) {
            continue;
          }



          var reader = new FileReader();

          // Closure to capture the file information.
          reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
            return function(e) {
            video.get(0).src = e.target.result;
            console.log(video.get(0));
            video.get(0).play();


              var span = document.createElement('span');
              span.innerHTML = "a video file";
              document.getElementById('list').insertBefore(span, null);
            };
          })(f);

          // Read in the image file as a data URL.
          reader.readAsDataURL(f);
        }
      }

      document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', 
      handleFileSelect, false);

    });


    function intializePlayer(){
    // Set object references
    vid = document.getElementById("my_video");
    vid.addEventListener('click',function(){
    vid.play();
    },false);
    playbtn = document.getElementById("playpausebtn");
    seekslider = document.getElementById("seekslider");
    curtimetext = document.getElementById("curtimetext");
    durtimetext = document.getElementById("durtimetext");
    mutebtn = document.getElementById("mutebtn");
    volumeslider = document.getElementById("volumeslider");
    fullscreenbtn = document.getElementById("fullscreenbtn");
    // Add event listeners
    playbtn.addEventListener("click",playPause,false);
    seekslider.addEventListener("change",vidSeek,false);
    vid.addEventListener("timeupdate",seektimeupdate,false);
    mutebtn.addEventListener("click",vidmute,false);
    volumeslider.addEventListener("change",setvolume,false);
    fullscreenbtn.addEventListener("click",toggleFullScreen,false);
    }
    window.onload = intializePlayer;
    function playPause(){
        if(vid.paused){
            vid.play();
            playbtn.style.background = "url(pause.png)";
        } else {
            vid.pause();
            playbtn.style.background = "url(play.png)";
    }
        }
    function vidSeek(){
    var seekto = vid.duration * (seekslider.value / 100);
    vid.currentTime = seekto;
    }
    function seektimeupdate(){
    var nt = vid.currentTime * (100 / vid.duration);
    seekslider.value = nt;
    var curmins = Math.floor(vid.currentTime / 60);
    var cursecs = Math.floor(vid.currentTime - curmins * 60);
    var durmins = Math.floor(vid.duration / 60);
    var dursecs = Math.floor(vid.duration - durmins * 60);
    if(cursecs < 10){ cursecs = "0"+cursecs; }
    if(dursecs < 10){ dursecs = "0"+dursecs; }
    if(curmins < 10){ curmins = "0"+curmins; }
    if(durmins < 10){ durmins = "0"+durmins; }
    curtimetext.innerHTML = curmins+":"+cursecs;
    durtimetext.innerHTML = durmins+":"+dursecs;
    }
    function vidmute(){
        if(vid.muted){
            vid.muted = false;
            mutebtn.innerHTML = "Mute";
        } else {
        vid.muted = true;
        mutebtn.innerHTML = "Unmute";
        }
    }
    function setvolume(){
    vid.volume = volumeslider.value / 100;
    }
    function toggleFullScreen(){
        if(vid.requestFullScreen){
            vid.requestFullScreen();
        } else if(vid.webkitRequestFullScreen){
            vid.webkitRequestFullScreen();
        } else if(vid.mozRequestFullScreen){
            vid.mozRequestFullScreen();
        }
    }
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="video_player_box">
        <input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple />
        <output id="list"></output>
        <video id="my_video" width="550" height="310" 
        onClick="this.play();">
        <source src="" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
        <div id="video_controls_bar">
            <button id="playpausebtn"></button>
            <input id="seekslider" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" 
            step="1">
            <span id="curtimetext">00:00</span> / <span 
             id="durtimetext">00:00</span>
            <button id="mutebtn">Mute</button>
            <input id="volumeslider" type="range" min="0" max="100" 
            value="100" step="1">
            <button id="fullscreenbtn">[ &nbsp; ]</button>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you sure that you already tested the official cordova media plugin? https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media

Comment: Nope, I haven't tried that.

Comment: Sithys, That plugin provides the ability to record and play back audio files on a device. Any help for video files?

Comment: Sorry for that Manu, thats correct. What about the cordova video player? https://github.com/moust/cordova-plugin-videoplayer

Comment: Sithys you're helping me. Please don't be sorry. And I'm afraid that this particular plugin is not supporting file fetching.

Answer (score 3):

### The Cordova Streaming Media Plugin

https://github.com/nchutchind/Streaming-Media-Cordova-Plugin

This is the one to use for showing videos in Cordova.
It works with local and remote streaming videos.

It is quite simple to use.
There is also this [step-by-step guide](https://github.com/krisrandall/streaming-media-plugin-demo) for creating a simple demo app that calls it which I made.

Comment: Finally, a video solution that works with local files in the data directory file:/// Thanks! The step-by-step guide was an excellent addition. I wish all plugins would include a demo, so we could have a version that's supposed to work. Running the demo app in my environment made it clear that the plugin *should* work with the platform I'm using, as long as I get the code right. Of course, the sample code is nice to have as well.

Comment: hello i will never try to play videos before. i work on ionic platform and create videos news related application for both android and iOS platform. so all videos i am facing form web API's and render in multiple thumbnails in my application UI. so which one you sagest video plugin its working fine for fulfill my requirements or not.? or you have any idea about this?.

Comment: If you wish to play video's full screen or if you want to play video files that are storred locally on the device (or bundled with your app) then use this plugin.  If you just want to have thumbnails embeded in your page, and all the videos are coming from the internet, then you can just use the html5 <video> tag

Comment: I have had 2 down votes on this answer - if you have down-voted could you please put a comment as to why ..

Comment: What file path should I use with this plugin if I am putting the video alongside html files

Comment: @anthonytherockjohnson (and @David) - which path to use is a question in itself - hopefully this is helpful : https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/

Comment: I hit a brick wall, I ended up going with native as it was far easier and I was beginning my build. But in the end it was a file path issue also just to make sure, try a video that has been properly encoded for android.